# Scheduling a batch process using UI- Which timezone does it schedule on?

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

When we schedule a batch process to run using UI, which timezone does it run?
Does it run on the user's timezone or the org's timezone or any other.

I need a particular schedulable batch to run on 1 of every month in australian time zone. 
Any link to documentation would be helpful

Comment: Anything you do in the UI, scheduling reports, scheduled classes, data exports, dashboards, etc will always be performed in the current user's time zone settings, unless specifically stated otherwise in the documentation for a specific feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [apex developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) shows that scheduled jobs follow users time zone

> The System.Schedule method uses the user's timezone for the basis of all schedules.

The easisest way would be to use a user who has locale set to australlian timezone else you will have to do the conversion and offset yourself .

**From UI it will use current running users timezone .**

Comment: Admittedly, the user is slightly confused, because the UI help text doesn't say anything about the time zone it runs in. While this answer is correct for scheduling in general, it doesn't explain the way the UI works.

Comment: @sfdcfox Good point just added to the answer .